# Cycle through rows to match 2 cells on separate worksheets CONTINUED

Tags: excel, vba, loops, match

I have the following code (courtesy of M.Schalk - thank you!) and am looking to delve deeper. In particular:

Every time a cell in column E of "sheet2" matches a cell in column C of "sheet1", I would like the cell contents of the cell in that row in column H of "sheet2" (3 cells to the right) to replace whats in column S if the matched row in "sheet1". I hope that makes sense!

Once the cell contents has been pasted, I would like the loop to continue and the next match to paste it's column H cell.

I know I've not explained this very well, so I will be suuupppeeerrrr appreciative if someone can work this one out!

```
Sub Test3()
  Dim x As String, y As String
  Dim found As Boolean
  Dim i As Integer, lastRow As Long

  lastRow = Worksheets("PLANNER_ONGOING_DISPLAY_SHEET").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

  x = "test 73"

  For i = 4 To lastRow
    'If you need to compare it to a cell in sheet2 you can also set the value of x here
    y = Worksheets("PLANNER_ONGOING_DISPLAY_SHEET").Cells(i, 3).Value2
    If y = x Then
        ' Do action here, example:
        MsgBox "Value found in cell " & "C" & i
    End If

  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Putting up a code you receive and asking how to modify it to meet your needs, is probably not going to get you anything. What have you tried? You could do some research on what you are trying to accomplish and then when you run into a problem, you can ask a specific question.  Being "suuupppeeerrrr appreciative " is great, but showing a little effort to accomplish the task, will get individuals to  provide constructive guidance.

Comment: I’m very new to this but will try to add my own code first in the future!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code checks for a specific value in one worksheet, but your asking to test for different values between two worksheet. So, I'm not too busy and I really want to be appreciated; so here is a basic macro that will loop through a column in one worksheet and test each cells value in another worksheets column for a match. If found it will offset 3 columns in the first worksheet and copy that value to the first worksheet column S current row.

```
'Define your variables
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, cel As Range, i As Long

'Assign your worksheet variables
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    'First loop through each cell in Sheet2, column E, start at row 2 to account
    'for header row) to get the value to find in sheet1, column C.
    For Each cel In ws2.Range("E2:E" & ws2.Range("E" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        'Then loop through each cell in Sheet1, Column C. If you get a match, then
        'copy the value from Sheet2, Column H, cel.row to Sheet1, Column S, i row.
        For i = 2 To ws1.Range("C" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            If cel.Value = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value Then
                ws1.Cells(i, 3).Offset(, 16).Value = cel.Offset(, 3).Value
            End If

        Next i 'loops through every used cell in Column C for all matches
    Next cel 'loop to the next cell in Sheets2, Columns E
```

Comment: Thank you GMalc, I will test this as soon as I get the chance!

Comment: Runs perfectly!! Thank you very much!